# How to build an extension for all Enums?

Tags: dart, enums

I currently have two enums

```
enum UserVisibleSettings {
  track,
  mark,
}

enum UserVisibleTwo {
  thing,
  otherthing,
}
```

And the goal is that I want to make an extension that will allow me to convert an enum into a `List<String>`

I'm able to make an extension on `UserVisibleSettings` or `UserVisibleTwo` but how can I make an extension on all enums?

Comment: Not possible in current version of Dart since enums does not have a shared interface in Dart which are specific for enums.

Comment: Feel free to create an answer and I'll accept it
@julemand101

Comment: This is basically https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35496.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in current version of Dart since enums does not have a shared interface in Dart which are specific for enums.